# Open a webpage in Android without showing its URL

Tags: android, url, browser, hide, fullscreen

How can I hide URL of the current webpage?

Or at least how can I display a webpage in fullscreen so as not to show the address bar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a WebView. Read more about it here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

EDIT:

Here is a simple example that loads a fullscreen webpage

```
package com.example.dhdh;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        WebView w = new WebView(this);
        w.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });
        w.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    setContentView(w);
    }
}
```

Also be sure to add this to your manifest

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

Comment: Another related [resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) that can help others.